# How to test PUT/PATCH API with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rspec

I am trying to test some PUT/PATCH endpoint from my API, but my 'record_to_update' is not chaging as expect.

I organize the spec as follow using Rails 5.2 and RSpec 3.8:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
  context 'when request with no valid headers' do
    ...
    ...
    ...
  end

  context 'when resquest with valid headers' do
    before do
      request.accept = 'application/vnd.api+json'
      request.content_type = 'application/vnd.api+json'

      2.times do
        create(:user)
      end
    end

    describe 'PATCH/PUT /users/:id' do
      let(:record_to_update) { create(:user) }
      let(:user_params) do
        { id: first_user.id, name: 'goku', email: 'goku@bol.com' }
      end

      before do
        put :update, params: { id: record_to_update, user: user_params }
        record_to_update.reload
      end

      it 'should update user' do
        expect(record_to_update.name).to eq('goku')
        expect(response.status).to eq 200
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As I said the problem here that I am facing is that 'record_to_update' is not chaging. I already test the same PUT/PATCH endpoint in the same API with Postman and successfully updated from there. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you should move the `before` block to `it 'should update user'`

```
  before do
    put :update, params: { id: record_to_update.id, user: user_params }

  end
```

So it becoming

```
it 'update user' do
  put :update, params: { id: record_to_update, user: user_params }
  expect ...
  record.reload!
....
end
```

Comment: I got the same failure "expected: "goku" and got: "Shandy Lear""

Comment: try `params: {id: record_to_update.id,  user: user_params}` and remove the id from user_params

Comment: Still the same :(, but I changed my 'record_to_update' var to create an user without FactoryBot and "solved it". So it became "User.create(name: 'somename', email: 'some@email.com')" instead "create(:user)". I think it might be something wrong in my factory